# Почему ширина не соответсвует указанной?

Tags: css, flexbox

Объясните пожалуйста, почему в примере ширина элемента уменьшается при указании flex-basis?
https://codepen.io/alyona_fedorenko1/pen/XWXByVd
В моем понимании левый блок должен занять 70% ширины родителя, т.е. стать 700px.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure dolorum consequuntur dolorem quam repellat nobis earum quo minus </div>
  <div class="child2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quis, explicabo nihil harum vel provident earum eum debitis assumenda iste officiis ducimus similique, deserunt corporis reiciendis. .</div>
</div>

.parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.child1 {
  flex-basis:70%;
}
```

Comment: А правый сколько должен занять? Если указать для child2 flex-basis 5%, то что должно получиться? А если 80% указать?

Comment: flex-basis jтвечает за изначальный размер элементов до того, как они будут изменены другими свойствами CSS Flexbox. Хотите ширину в 70%, задайте её свойством width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не так работает. Если ширина не указана, то по умолчанию 100%. Для child1 указано 70%, для child2 берется 100%. Итого 170%. И 1000px и есть эти 170%. Из них 7/17 дается левому блоку, 10/17 - правому.

Comment: https://codepen.io/alyona_fedorenko1/pen/XWXByVd
Если задать элементу ширину 70%, срабатывает по такой же логике как и flex-basis. Можете подсказать, если стоит все-таки задача для child1 отдать 70% ширины родителя, как это лучше сделать?